# How to plot numerically the wave functions according to the Hamiltonian?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, hamiltonian, software

It is often difficult to analytically solve the Schrodinger equation, and so we need to obtain a solution numerically.
An example plot is shown below.

Here, the wave functions for a three junction flux qubit are plotted.
The Hamiltonian is
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{\hat{P}_p^2}{M_p} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\hat{P}_m}{M_m}
+ E_J \left[ 2 + \alpha - 2 \cos \hat{\phi_p} \cos \hat{\phi_m} - \alpha \cos \left( 2 \pi f_x^\text{DC} + 2 \hat{\phi}_m \right) \right]$$
where
$$\hat{P}_p \equiv -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{\phi}_p} \qquad
\hat{P}_m \equiv -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{\phi}_m}$$
and $M_p$ and $M_m$ are the effective masses of the two coordinates.

I don’t fully understand how to achieve from the equation to the figure.
What method or software can be used to solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give reference of the book.

Comment: http://www.wmi.badw.de/publications/theses.htm《New Trends in Superconducting Circuit Quantum Electrodynamics: Two Amplifiers, Two Resonators, and Two Photons》 2009   PhD thesis, Mariantoni, Matteo

Comment: as mentioned on page 76

Comment: This problem is slightly nontrivial because there are two degrees of freedom. Let's start at the beginning: do you know how to numerically solve a Hamiltonian with one degree of freedom?

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve partial differential equations? If not, I would suggest you start with the "simple" ones, like a diffusion equation.

Comment: @DanielSank , Thank you very much.
I am a beginner, so I don't know the correct procedures to settle problems.
could you like to give me some instructions?

Comment: @CuriousOne ,  use Matlab ?

Comment: I would start by looking into books about partial differential equations. Numerics are only useful if you understand the general behavior of an equation to some extent.

Comment: Ok, in that case I would recommend asking a similar question to this one, but with only a single coordinate, as it's easier to understand. If there isn't already a question like that on the site, post one and like to it here and I'll answer it.

Comment: @DanielSank,  I post the  one dimensional equation. However, how to extand to two dimensional equation ?

Comment: Please use text and equations rather than an image. Also, it would be better to ask a specific question; right now we have a two dimensional Hamiltonian *and* a one dimensional one.

Comment: @DanielSank, 
This is simple example (One-dimensional Schrodinger equation)


$$\frac{d^2 \psi }{dx^2} + k^2 \psi(x) =0 $$

$$\psi(-1) = \psi(1) =0 $$
here
$$
    k^2(x)  = \frac{2m}{\hbar^2} \bigl[  E - V(x) \bigr], \qquad
V(x)  = V_0 \bigl[ x^2/2-1 \bigr]
$$

we set 

$$  \gamma = \Bigl[  \frac{ 2mV_0}{\hbar^2} \Bigr]^{1/2} $$
    
   {set   $\gamma =50$ in matlab } 

$$  \epsilon  = E/V_0 $$

So the Schrodinger equation become
   
$$
      \Bigl[ - \frac{1}{\gamma^2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} +  x^2/2-1 - \epsilon
      \Bigr]\psi(x) =0
$$

Comment: function wlch5
global e1
n= 4 ; eold =-1; olddpsi =0.5; tol =1e-6;
for k=1:n
    de = 2*tol; e1= eold + abs(eold)/70;
    while abs(de) >tol
        xturn = -sqrt(2*(e1+1)); kk =(-1)^(k+1)*0.0001;
        [x1,u1] = ode45(@wlch5fun,[-1 xturn],[0 kk]);
        [x2,u2] = ode45(@wlch5fun,[ 1 xturn],[0 -0.0001]);
        dpsi =u1(length(x1),2) - u2(length(x2),2);
        de = -dpsi*de/(dpsi-olddpsi);
        olddpsi = dpsi; eold=e1; e1=e1+de;
    end
    e(k) =eold;
    subplot(2,2,k); plot(x1,u1(:,1),x2,u2(:,1))
end
e
diff(e)

Comment: function yy= wlch5fun(x,psi)
global e1 
  yy = [psi(2); 50^2*(-e1-1+x^2/2)*psi(1)];

Comment: how to set MATLAB syntax highlighting?